# JavaScript different programming styles

Tags: javascript, oop, styles

I'm trying to learn new styles of JavaScript programming and what it is capable of. I've come across what I think are three different styles of development and honestly do not understand when and why to use them. I'm looking for some guidance on this, unless it's purely a style thing.

I've put questions inline for each style:

**1) JavaScript Object Oriented Programming:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

- What benefit does creating a Tree constructor, or invoking `new node()` have over just not using `new`? In the other examples, I can just return the node, or just the result of what the `node` function produces, and that's perfectly fine.
- Why would I add a class member, like a function, retroactively, like `Tree.prototype.doStuff = function() {`? Why can't I just include the function from the start?

--

```
(function () {

    var Tree = function () {
         this.nodeList = [];
         this.nodeList.push(new node("A", 100, 100), etc...);
         etc...
    };

    var node = function (name, x, y) {
         this.el = document.createElement("span");
         this.el.innerHTML = name;
         etc...
         return this;
    };

    var tree1 = new Tree();

    Tree.prototype.doStuff = function() {
          ...
    }

    var myFunc = tree1.doStuff;

    myFunc.call(tree);

})();
```

**2) Create anonymous function object Tree as Self-executing anonymous function:**

- This was taken from [melonJS canvas renderer](https://github.com/melonjs/melonJS/blob/1.1.x/src/video/canvas_renderer.js). Why do they need to create Tree as a self-invoking function, and store methods as properties of `api` object? I don't understand the point of this style.

--

```
(function () {

  Tree = (function () {
     var api = {},
         nodeList = [];

     api.init = function () {
          nodeList = [];
          nodeList.push(node("A", 100, 100), etc...);
     };

     api.node = function (name, x, y) {
        var el = document.createElement("span");
        el.innerHTML = name;
        etc...
        return el;
     };

     api.doStuff = function () {
         ...
     };

     return api;
  })();
})();
```

**3) Create object namespace with functions:**

- This is the way I am used to. What benefit does this have over the other styles?

--

```
(function () {

    var Tree = Tree || {};

    var Tree = {
        nodeList : [],
        init : function () {
             this.nodeList = [];
             this.nodeList.push(node("A", 100, 100), etc...);
             this.doStuff();
        },
        node : function (name, x, y) {
            var el = document.createElement("span");
            el.innerHTML = name;
            etc...
            return el;
        },
        doStuff : function () {
            ...
        }
    };
    Tree.init();
})();
```

Comment: I just do what Crockford does. Don't write code that has `new` or `this`. Added complexity for no benefit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bo36MrBfTk4&t=1125

Comment: You should ask a single question per... question.

Comment: @FelixKling I know, but I wanted to lay out the different styles in one question so people can compare.

Answer (score 0):

As for question #2 there are a few reason it's done like that. 
There are probably more than I list now, but these are the ones that come to mind, and essentially boil down to "It's nice", "Function scope, frick yeah" and "Tree is undefined within itself";

So, firstly, the self-initializing function thingies allow you to write

```
Tree.doStuff()
```

Instead of

```
Tree().doStuff()
```

Which looks nice. 
Also, with the self-initialized syntax, `Tree()` is only called on the initial load, whereas `Tree().doStuff()` invokes `Tree()` everytime. 
Strengths, weaknesses depending on use-case.

For the second part of your question:
1) the dot-syntax means "I want to access this property on that object", and in order to do that an object must be returned from the function.

2) if we declare methods like

```
Tree = (function () {
 var api = {},
     nodeList = [];

 doStuff2 = function () {
     console.log("hej2");
 };
...
```

`doStuff2` is encapsulated in a function, and JavaScript has function scope, so it's basically a private method. No-go.

3) If we instead try to put the methods on `Tree`, like this:

```
Tree = (function () {
 var api = {},
     nodeList = [];

 Tree.doStuff2 = function () {
     console.log("hej2");
 };
...
```

Then `Tree` is not defined in `Tree`. 
If you haven't already, I recommend finding a good guide on the Module Pattern, perhaps this one: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

There are a couple of ways of emplyoing the pattern, with strengths and weaknesses.

Answered to the best of my abilities, please tell me if I should clarify, add or correct.